# C++/CLI marshaling delegate with string argument to wchar_t*

Tags: c++, string, c++-cli

I am trying to marshal a callback function in C++/CLI. The following example only prints an "H" so the marshaling of the wide chars to the managed string doesn't seem to work even though I have specified [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::LPWStr)].

Also tried marshaling using BSTRs but got the same result.

```
typedef void(*PFN_PRINT)(const wchar_t*);

void PrintHej(PFN_PRINT pfnPrint)
{
    pfnPrint(L"Hej");
}

ref class PrinterClass
{
public:
    static void Printer(String^ str)
    {
        Console::WriteLine(str);
    }
};

delegate void PrinterDelegate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::LPWStr)] String^);

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    PrinterDelegate^ pDelegate = gcnew PrinterDelegate(&PrinterClass::Printer);
    GCHandle gch = GCHandle::Alloc(pDelegate);

    IntPtr pFn = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(pDelegate);
    PrintHej(static_cast<PFN_PRINT>(pFn.ToPointer()));

    gch.Free();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The typedef is for a function that uses the default calling convention.  Which is `__cdecl`, not what the marshaler expects.  Apply [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention::Cdecl, CharSet=CharSet::Unicode)] to the delegate declaration.